# pivot to wide dataframe with repeating column names

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataframe that I need to get into the right configuration for an external program (PRISM Graphpad). In this toy example I have a matrix of 5x3 conditions with duplicate measurements for each condition. Originally for plotting and analysis in R the data is in the proper long tidy format.

While I am comfortable pivoting the data, I run into problems that the values are not unique when pivoting the DF wide. I need the replicates to be in adjacent columns with the same name for PRISM to properly recognize things. However, when I pivot wide, the duplicate values get shoved into a list because they do not have a unique identified in the id_cols.

In the real-life example the matrix of conditions is of course much larger, there are more repeats (but an identical number for each condition), and on top of that every df is an entry in a list-column, so I will likely need to apply the solution using a purrr::map function.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(rep(LETTERS[seq(1,5)], 2)),
              "cond1" = runif(10, 0, 1),
              "cond2" = runif(10, 1, 10),
              "cond3" = runif(10, 10, 100))


#// original long dataframe
long_df <- pivot_longer(data = df, cols = c("cond1", "cond2", "cond3"))
long_df
#> # A tibble: 30 x 3
#>    ID    name   value
#>    <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 A     cond1  0.424
#>  2 A     cond2  9.01 
#>  3 A     cond3 61.6  
#>  4 B     cond1  0.460
#>  5 B     cond2  2.33 
#>  6 B     cond3 40.3  
#>  7 C     cond1  0.107
#>  8 C     cond2  5.82 
#>  9 C     cond3 23.9  
#> 10 D     cond1  0.714
#> # ... with 20 more rows


#// desired output
desired_df <- cbind(df[c(1:5),], df[c(6:10),])
desired_df <- desired_df[,c(1,2,6,3,7,4,8)]
colnames(desired_df)[c(3,5,7)] <- c("cond1", "cond2", "cond3")
desired_df
#>   ID     cond1     cond1    cond2    cond2    cond3    cond3
#> 1  A 0.4244798 0.8078372 9.005544 5.349371 61.61488 73.80651
#> 2  B 0.4596927 0.3509671 2.325029 8.636263 40.33949 66.54288
#> 3  C 0.1069974 0.3903294 5.817079 7.100623 23.87013 99.98683
#> 4  D 0.7144698 0.1005499 9.886948 7.006333 19.40680 66.86696
#> 5  E 0.2903691 0.6177356 8.890734 9.863695 46.56568 66.42537


#// result from pivot_wider
wide_df <- pivot_wider(long_df, id_cols = ID, names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
#> * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
#> * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
#> * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
wide_df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   ID    cond1     cond2     cond3    
#>   <chr> <list>    <list>    <list>   
#> 1 A     <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
#> 2 B     <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
#> 3 C     <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
#> 4 D     <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
#> 5 E     <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
.0)

Comment: It is not recomended to have column names duplicates

Comment: Understood. It's not what I would be doing in R, but I believe it is a prerequisite for the downstream software to properly group repeats together. And thank you for the solution. Clearly I should just make the names unique, pivot, and then I can simply alter then names if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to have duplicate column names, therefore, we modify the 'name' column by appending an unique index created with `rowid`, and use that to reshape with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
long_df %>% 
   mutate(name = str_c(name, "_", rowid(ID, name))) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value, names_sort = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
#  ID    cond1_1 cond1_2 cond2_1 cond2_2 cond3_1 cond3_2
#  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A       0.293   0.920    6.44    9.14    18.5    71.9
#2 B       0.225   0.280    4.34    2.78    59.7    16.9
#3 C       0.704   0.764    7.05    1.40    75.3    64.0
#4 D       0.519   0.802    7.06    5.51    22.4    66.7
#5 E       0.663   0.255    3.88    2.25    30.1    14.2
```

If it needs to have repeating names, just strip off the `_\\d+` at the end of the name with `str_remove`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
new <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  group_by(ID,name) %>%
  mutate(name=paste0(name,'.',row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_sort = T,names_from=name,values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   ID [5]
  ID    cond1.1 cond1.2 cond2.1 cond2.2 cond3.1 cond3.2
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A       0.619   0.851    4.49    9.17    70.9    84.2
2 B       0.989   0.542    9.64    3.57    55.3    28.3
3 C       0.594   0.602    5.16    8.97    26.2    19.0
4 D       0.349   0.244    5.29    8.52    44.8    17.7
5 E       0.683   0.848    7.27    8.07    97.3    73.9
```

Then you can process like this:

```
#Further process
names(new) <- gsub("\\..*","",names(new))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   ID [5]
  ID    cond1 cond1 cond2 cond2 cond3 cond3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     0.129 0.360  4.60  2.74  55.3  58.3
2 B     0.416 0.384  5.93  9.17  15.7  21.8
3 C     0.724 0.622  9.30  7.81  76.9  79.0
4 D     0.101 0.951  6.35  1.58  30.3  68.5
5 E     0.238 0.814  9.46  9.50  12.4  57.8
```

And export to .txt for the other software.